# Как изменить атрибут при ресайзе?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Подскажите, как сделать, что бы плагин добавлял атрибут не `style="height: 0px;"`, а `style="min-height: 0px;` ?

```
$( "#content" ).resizable({
    handles: "s",
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю есть ли такой функционал, но я решил свою проблему таким способом:

```
$( "#content" ).resizable({
        handles: "s",
        start: function() {
            $(this).css({
                "minHeight": "auto",
                "height": "auto"
            });
        },
        stop: function() {
            var elHeight = $(this).height();
            $(this).css({
                "minHeight": elHeight + "px",
                "height": "inherit"
            });
        }
    });
```